# how to fix gradle unable to install Git Hooks?

Tags: git, gradle

When I run

`.\gradlew installGitHooks` i am gettin below error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Task 'installGitHooks' not found in root project 'abc' and its subprojects.

Can some one advice me on how to install Git Hooks with gradle.

Comment: It isn't standard in gradle, but you can find plugins to do it.  For [example](https://github.com/gtramontina/ghooks.gradle).  But, there are a few of them.